# Oracle Rest Data Service (ORDS) URL link

Tags: java, oracle-ords

I have installed ORDS 3.0 on Centos 7 and using it in standalone mode, but 
I am currently having two issues:

- The URL contains /ords, e.g.: http://localhost/ords.  I want to change it to /apex instead.  I have tried renaming ords.war to apex.war, but the URL hasn't changed.
- I am unable to start ORDS at system boot.  I have created a systemctl service for it, but ORDS stops after starting.

Comment: rename ords.war to apex.war and do everything normal. That will make it /apex

Comment: I jus tsaw your comment here, sorry previously it just went by me , but i have tried renaming ords.war to apex.war but then when i access it through link ords does a redirect and then change **/apex** to **/ords** again

Comment: to be specific it does **302** http redirect i found that in logs

Comment: The process i used download **ords > unzip > change ords.war to apex.war > java -jar apex.war** 

then configured settings still it redirects to url with name ords.war

Comment: never a reason to unzip the file. Standalone may not be best choice for you. Using tomcat may work out easier. I'll get an example posted.

Comment: i meant unzip package not the war file, i was able to do it with tomcat and ords was changed to apex, but due to redirection from ords itself url rewriting is not working such as changing f?p=123 of apexx to something nicer

Comment: Is there something wrong i am doing in the process which is causing it to not showing as /apex instead of /ords in url?

Answer (score 1):

The specific version of ORDS can be important, things do change quite a bit from version 3.0 to 3.9 for example.

However...

Starting ORDS in your init tab scripts is pretty much like anything else, you should be able to nohup it and redirect the output to a log file. If you're doing this, what's the log file showing, WHY is it stopping after it starts?

And the URL's - since you're running ORDS in standalone mode, you can take advantage of the embedded Jetty webserver that's being used.

That means you can config how URI's are rewritten. [Kris](https://twitter.com/krisrice) has an example of how to do this [here](https://krisrice.io/2018-04-24-ords-standalone-and-uri-rewrites/).

How to map /catalog to /ords/klrice/metadata-catalog/

```
<Call name="addRule">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
             <Set name="pattern">/catalog</Set>
             <Set name="replacement">/ords/klrice/metadata-catalog/</Set>
           </New>
         </Arg>
       </Call>
</Ref>
```

Comment: Thank you jeff , i checked out links, will take some time to implement them and post results, About ords not starting up at startup I will post logs after the URL work.

Comment: I checked the links you provided

Service not starting issue is now resolved it was shell script mistake which is corrected from the links you have provided.

And for now i am just leaving jetty for url rewrite i will be sticking with apache url rewriting methods since server have apache running as well.
Thank you so much for the help really appreciate it

Comment: Cool, apache, weblogic, etc all make this avail on the URL rewrites. If you build something cool, be sure to share with @oraclerest on Twitter.

Comment: Will definitely share if something is done in this regard

Comment: So far it turns out since ords app creates redirect to link /ords/f ....   there seems no way to hide /ords part from url using apache.

Comment: Now I am trying to do same using jetty using info on kris blog and the code you mentioned above but still if i set **pattern = /catalog** and **replacement = /ords** it keeps showing ords in url even if i access it like mydomain.com/catalog , I guess same apache issue is happening here too any idea?