# Advantage/Disadvantages of oracle ORDS in standalone mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-ords

I am wondering if anyone can guide me about the advantages or disadvantages of using oracle ORDS in standalone mode versus using it with some server such as Glassfish or Tomcat.

I am using ords 3.09 if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

For standalone ORDS, we use Jetty ( www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/ ). Jetty is a very capable webserver that on my laptop scale to 200+ rest calls per second. There deeper details on it's scaling abilities here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/high-load.html

The best advantage is it simply works, scales, easy to get up and running. We use this in Oracle Cloud DBCS so it works in production just dandy.

The disadvantage is mainly it's a purpose built and configured web server for ORDS. If someone needs more general web server features, it'd best to use WLS / Tomcat / Glassfish.

Comment: Thank you for the details analysis , that really helps

Comment: Anytime. I run the ords product team so hit me up for any questions.

Comment: Please kindly look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568837/oracle-rest-data-service-ords-url-link    question of mine if you can help me with url rewriting

Comment: Sure I’ll get it shortly.

Comment: Need your help on ords https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488026/ords-webservice-internal-server-error-500