# Ords webservice Internal server error 500

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using ords to front oracle apex, recently it started giving me 500 internal server error with no reason on page, the error is displayed when ever i try to test webservcice (i.e. click on webservice test button form oracle apex), below is the log for ords

```
    SEVERE: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleResultSetImpl.isClosed()Z is abstract
InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[]]
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.ResourceTemplatesServlet.canDispatch(ResourceTemplatesServlet.java:108)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.ResourceTemplatesServlet.canDispatch(ResourceTemplatesServlet.java:69)
    at oracle.dbtools.dispatch.DispatchableChooser.choose(DispatchableChooser.java:36)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.choose(Dispatcher.java:69)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:98)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint$FilteredServlet.service(EntryPoint.java:240)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.QueryFilteringRewrite.doFilter(QueryFilteringRewrite.java:90)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFilter.java:68)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSPreflightFilter.doFilter(CORSPreflightFilter.java:66)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cookies.auth.CookieSessionCSRFFilter.doFilter(CookieSessionCSRFFilter.java:77)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.authenticate(AuthenticationFilter.java:87)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:62)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.RequestMapperImpl.doFilter(RequestMapperImpl.java:125)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:103)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.filter.URLMappingFilter.doFilter(URLMappingFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:83)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:82)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchableServices(HttpEndpointBase.java:116)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleResultSetImpl.isClosed()Z is abstract
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.isClosed(OracleResultSetImpl.java)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.ResultSetIterator.advance(ResultSetIterator.java:59)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.ResultSetIterator.advance(ResultSetIterator.java:20)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator._advance(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.start(AbstractIterator.java:153)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:79)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.query.QueryPagination$PaginatedResultRows.hasNext(QueryPagination.java:108)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.JDBCResultRowIterator.hasNext(JDBCResultRowIterator.java:62)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Iterators$AlsoCloseIterator.hasNext(Iterators.java:477)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Iterators$SelectorIterator.advance(Iterators.java:599)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator._advance(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.start(AbstractIterator.java:153)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:79)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.TransformIterator.hasNext(TransformIterator.java:55)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Iterators$SelectorIterator.advance(Iterators.java:599)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator._advance(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.start(AbstractIterator.java:153)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:79)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Iterators.add(Iterators.java:51)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.util.Iterators.add(Iterators.java:33)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.uri.URITemplates.choose(URITemplates.java:65)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.resource.templates.jdbc.JDBCResourceTemplates.resourceTemplate(JDBCResourceTemplates.java:43)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.resource.templates.jdbc.JDBCResourceTemplates.resourceTemplate(JDBCResourceTemplates.java:23)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.resource.templates.v2.ResourceTemplatesDispatcher.canDispatch(ResourceTemplatesDispatcher.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.resource.templates.jdbc.JDBCResourceTemplateDispatcher.canDispatch(JDBCResourceTemplateDispatcher.java:48)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.RequestDispatchers.choose(RequestDispatchers.java:217)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.RequestDispatchers.canDispatch(RequestDispatchers.java:59)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.ResourceTemplatesServlet.choose(ResourceTemplatesServlet.java:193)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.ResourceTemplatesServlet.canDispatch(ResourceTemplatesServlet.java:97)
    ... 61 more
```

So far i have found that this maybe happening cause of ojdbc driver outdate, my ords version is 3.0.9.348.07.16 , and oracle version  is 11.2.0.2.0 64bit any idea what is causing this or what might be solution for this

Thank you

Comment: >>cause of ojdbc driver outdate<< - there should be no problem with version compatibility between ORDS 309 and DB 11gR2. Try flipping this to TRUE defaults.xml config file, the  debug.debugger entry.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i just flipped debug.debugger to true but i see exactly the same error in logs

Comment: which version of java and are you running this standalone or say with tomcat?

Comment: I am running it in standalone with java version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: It was working just fine until recently it just started to giving 500 internal server error on webservices only otherwise apex applications are working fine

Comment: This is something with the jdbc but should be fine since we pack it and no option to change it. Try ords 17.4 which is current version. I think, something env is messing it up

Comment: I just reinstalled ords for the same version and it worked, but still dont have a clue what gone wrong